# Graph/chart that supports dynamic pie charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, graph, charts

Does anyone know of a good charting/graphing tool that supports dynamic pie charts, i.e. where a user could change the values by dragging, etc?  It would need an event API so I could get access to the changed values.

And, jQuery > vanilla JS > Flash.

Answer (score 0):

- **jqplot** : jquery, charts, easy to use. Almost fulfill all of your requirements. Details [here](http://www.jqplot.com). Only one problem : not sure that you can change values dynamically or it might be tricky
- **HighCharts** : very good quality, higly configurable, vanilla JS. Check this demo for **dynamically adding values** (even graphically) : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-click-to-add&theme=gray

Answer (score 0):

I gave up searching/tweaking and [implemented my own](https://github.com/tfwright/adjustable-pie-chart) using Raphael.  It's still very buggy, but I think it's a good proof of concept.  Forks welcome :)